# Effect of infected excel to MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I have this application I'm building that requires a user to download an excel file then fill the form after which they upload it back.

#### My concerns

Considering I can't trust all my users that they would only fill the form and upload it back to the application, I fear that an attacker might infect the excel file with macros then upload it to my application. I'm afraid that it might mess my db up.

Application built on PHP

DB: MySQL

Is it safe this way? If no, I'll appreciate if someone can suggest to me a safe way to implement this

Comment: Set it up for a csv file only needs to be transferred.

Comment: Web application with client and server-side data validation is better. In case fields are in large number or if excel has to be used, CSV or XML data set is better.

Comment: You can't import Excel macros into a database really, at least not without knowingly doing so in your import process. The macros can't execute outside the Excel environment either. If you discard the file after you've imported the data alone, and never actually open the file in Excel, it shouldn't really pose a threat. Having said that, using CSV would remove any risk entirely.

Comment: Depending on the type of data the users are adding to the Excel file, you would also be sanitizing the data for expected data types (as I'm assuming you would be parsing the file and not storing the actual uploaded file). It might be worth looking into Excel APIs in PHP (like PHPSpreadsheet) that may allow you to remove macros.

Comment: Actually what is the reason that Excel sheet is required? Most probably you can prepare online form and handle it as an app, as already suggested.